# Puedo usar un if para completar las filas de una columna agregada en una consulta SQL

Tags: sql

tengo este select

```
SELECT re.fecha AS Fecha, 
re.equipo1 AS EquipoLocal, 
te.name AS EquipoVisitante, 
re.resultado AS Resultado, 
CASE WHEN re.resultado = 'Local' THEN re.equipo1 
WHEN re.resultado = 'Visitante' THEN te.name 
ELSE 'Empate' 
END AS EquipoGanador 
FROM team AS te, (SELECT ma.date AS Fecha, t.name AS Equipo1, mt.id_visitorteam AS Equipo2, mr.description AS Resultado FROM match_team2 AS mt, team AS t, matchresult AS mr, [match] AS ma WHERE mt.id_localteam=t.id_team AND mt.id_matchresult = mr.id_matchresult AND mt.id_match = ma.id_match) AS re 
WHERE re.equipo2 = te.id_team AND re.fecha BETWEEN #03/01/2020# AND #02/18/2024#;
```

Lo que quiero es agregar una columna "EquipoGanador" en la que si Resultado = Local, me inscriba en "EquipoGanador" el nombre de EquipoLocal. Si Resultado = Visitante, inscriba el nombre de EquipoVisitante.

Comment: Pon la estructura de tus tablas y un ejemplo con datos reales, da todos los detalles necesarios para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Que gestor de base de datos usas?

Comment: Ahí tienes una posible solución utilizando el IIf, y borra tu respuesta ya que he modificado tu pregunta poniendo el código que has enviado.

Comment: @Stefan deja que OP sea quien agregue el código en su propia pregunta.

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya está resuelto. Soy nuevo por acá, ya aprenderé mejor cómo funciona el tema preguntar y responder.

Comment: @Sebastian si ya está resuelto, pon como respuesta (ahora sí) qué has hecho para resolver tu planteamiento. Cuando puedas, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil (si es la tuya, deberás esperar 48 horas). Y tampoco olvides colocar la consulta que tenías previamente como edición a tu pregunta: recuerda que tu pregunta y sus respuestas deberían ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para quienes tengan un problema similar más adelante.

Comment: Puedes agregar con que base de datos estas trabajando `mssql, mysql, postgresql, etc.` con esto podemos ayudarte con tu cuonsulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ultilizar la funcion IIf que es específica de Access. En este ejemplo, Si es ‘Local’, entonces EquipoGanador será re.equipo1. Si es ‘Visitante’, entonces EquipoGanador será te.name.

```
SELECT
    re.fecha AS Fecha,
    re.equipo1 AS EquipoLocal,
    te.name AS EquipoVisitante,
    re.resultado AS Resultado,
    IIf(re.resultado = 'Local', re.equipo1, te.name) AS EquipoGanador
FROM
    team AS te,
    (
        SELECT
            ma.date AS Fecha,
            t.name AS Equipo1,
            mt.id_visitorteam AS Equipo2,
            mr.description AS Resultado
        FROM
            match_team2 AS mt,
            team AS t,
            matchresult AS mr,
            [match] AS ma
        WHERE
            mt.id_localteam = t.id_team
            AND mt.id_matchresult = mr.id_matchresult
            AND mt.id_match = ma.id_match
    ) AS re
WHERE
    re.equipo2 = te.id_team
    AND re.fecha BETWEEN #03/01/2020# AND #02/18/2024;
```

Comment: Hola, gracias, había probado algo así, pero cuando pruebo esa consulta en Access me dice "error de sintaxis"

Comment: Proporciona toda la consulta para poderte ayudar mejor, ya que el error puede estar otro lugar.

Comment: Gracias, ahora sí funcionó!

Comment: Si la respuesta de @Stefan te funcionó, márcala como aceptada